# The theory optionsValue and value in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am using optionsValue and value in my knockout databind. However, what I really want is that if I want to preselect an item, I should be (atleast I presume) able to populate the variable assigned to value and it should give me a preselected item. However, it appears undefined at the start. Clearly I am misunderstanding something. What is it that I am doing wrong.

```
<select data-bind="options: lookupgender, optionsText: 'description', optionsValue: 'code', value: choice,optionsCaption: '-Gender-'"></select>
```

The whole code is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5TLw/) and I expected this to select "female".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch this:

```
this.choice = choices[1];
```

To this:

```
this.choice = ko.observable(choices[1].code);
```

Or even just this:

```
this.choice = ko.observable('F');
```

There were two problems:

- The `choice` was not an observable, that means a binding can't be formed between the underlying value and the selected option.
- The initial value of `choice` was a whole object `{ code: 'F', description: "Female" }`. But you specified `code` as `optionsValue`, so `choice` should have either value `'F'` or `'M'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your syntax slightly:

```
function ViewModel(choices) {
   this.lookupgender = ko.observableArray(choices);
   this.choice = ko.observable(choices[1].code); 
};
```